# How to wrap h2 tag until next h2 found in wrapper div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic HTML file. It's essentially a blog post worth of content, with `<h2>` tags seperating different content zones.

```html
<h2>Header A</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<h2>Header B</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<h2>Header C</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
```

What I want to do is have javascript add an HTML `wrapper` class at the start of the `<h2>` tag it sees, and close it upon seeing the next `<h2>` tag like so.

This way I can write blog content naturally in markdown, but customize the look and feel of a site. So I can focus on content and not forgetting whether I closed tags properly

Below is a simple example where I add margins, padding, and opacity hover effects. This is the end result that I want.

*The `<h2>` tags are all going to be at the same level in the DOM.*

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.wrapper:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Header A</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Header B</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Header C</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
</div>
```

I imagine I could use a `document.querySelector("h2")`, or some sort of `:nth-of-type` pseudoselector, grab the element right before next `<h2>`, and add a parent class to everything. But I am not entirely sure how this is implemented.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/ helps, all you got to do is get the selection of the h2 and following elements right ;-)

Comment: Sorry it's been awhile since I've posted on stackoverflow, I will do more research / prototyping next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through `h2` and in loop select next siblings of `h2` using [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and wrap selected elements in new tag using [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```js
$("h2").each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil("h2").add(this).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.wrapper:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Header A</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<h2>Header B</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<h2>Header C</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the `.wrapAll` method from jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parentNode.insertBefore` function to acheive this in `javascript`

Something like this,

**EDIT**

Have a (same) dummy class assigned to your `h2` and `p` tags like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="insideElement">Header B</h2>
  <p class="insideElement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
  <p class="insideElement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</p>
</div>
```

And then you can use the `querySelectorAll` method to get that,

```
function wrapElement(el, wrapper) {
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
}

var createElem = document.createElement('div');
createElem.className='wrapper';

wrapElement(document.querySelectorAll('.insideElement'), createElem);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would wrap the `h2` in a `div`. OP wants to also wrap the following `p` tags in the same `div`.

Comment: It didn't exactly work though any suggestions? https://i.imgur.com/Zii762Z.png . This was helpful though David, I needed a nice starting point :)

Comment: but this defeats the point though, I want to write simple markdown content and have javascript/jquery handle the wrapping class for styling. The other answer works though, I'll have to checkout how jquery `wrapAll` is implemented to see how a native JS implementation would be written

Comment: Cool then!.. :-)

Comment: David would you happen to know where the most common list of element's methods are for this application? Or how to see the element's methods in the console at a glance? I know you can do this for `events` though. I thought it would be something like `document.querySelector("h2").xxxx` where xxxx is a command i don't remember.

For instance, if you typed `document.querySelector("h2").nextSibling`, you get a list of results / values that each method gives. https://i.imgur.com/rvj6UGo.png

Comment: Store it in a variable like `var someObj=document.querySelectorAll('.insideElement')`; and when you do a `console.log` like `console.log(someObj)` you will get the `NodeList` to introspect.